# Create SSH user for Unison with the fewest rights

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-networking, unison

I would like to share a directory on my server so that a colleague can synchronize it via Unison (two ways synchronization). I don't want him to be able to read files on the server via ssh access. It would be best if the ssh user can't log in, but only synchronizes via unison. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: There is the ill-advised [socket method of connecting to the server](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#socketmeth).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `command=` option in the `authorized_keys` file to force running Unison when the user connects via ssh. This means they cannot get a login shell. You can also disable port forwarding and other ssh features in this file.

The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` line would look something like this (note the `-server` option for Unison):

```
command="/usr/bin/unison -server",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty,no-agent-forwarding,no-user-rc ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y....
```

I haven't tested this.

For more information on the `command=` ssh option, see [Restrict executable SSH commands with authorized keys](https://www.virtono.com/community/tutorial-how-to/restrict-executable-ssh-commands-with-authorized-keys/).

Alternatively, you could use a VPN or ssh port-forwarding to encrypt the connection in the socket method which Mike Pierce mentioned above, but this would probably be more complex.